# Issue Creating EC2 with Provisioned iops EBS

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

i am trying to create a AWS EC2 instance with:

```
Redhat 6.5,
HVM virtulization,
EBS optimized: true,
volume Type: Provisioned IOPS,
EBS Size: 200 GB,
iops: 4000
```

than add name, Security Group, key and launch instance. it says launching and when i view the instance it gets terminated automatically.strange issue....i tried different OS. same issue , i guess issue with with when i select Provisioned iops. if i go with standard it creates the instance but with limited IOPS. any idea???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every Account has a limited number of IOPS that can be attached to the volumes.I think the limit per account is set to 10000. This may be the reason why your instances are getting terminated. Check for all volumes that you already have IOPS associated and add them up to see if you are exceeding the limit.

If this is the issue I think you can contact AWS to increase the limit.

Comment: Yup, see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws_service_limits.html#limits_ebs.

Comment: Nice Catch Rahul, let me check.

Comment: yes i am currently on 9500 and was trying to create a volume with 4000 IOPS seems like my limit is reaching. thanks alot appreciate that.